# Integrating Google Maps Data API with iPhone and performing search

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

Has anyone integrated Google's Maps Data API available [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client), with iPhone application. If so can you please share the skeleton code to get an head start in my application?

I want to search some nearby places (for user information e.g. park, theatre, etc.) with respect to current location using Google Maps Data API.

Answer (score 13):

I just published some simple iOS classes that use Google's Local Search API to get location information about places in a map region via a name or address search.  There are [detailed instructions here](http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/), and [the GitHub repository is here](https://github.com/vvanhee/Google-Local-Search-iOS).

Hopefully, this information will make it very easy for new developers to use the Google Local API in an iPhone app to get the latitude & longitude of businesses & other places.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this code is what you're after.

```
NSString *url =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q='%@'&sll=%f,%f&rsz=large&start=0",query, location.latitude, location.longitude];
```

You may also want to review
https://github.com/twoism/gkit

Answer (score 2):

follow [these steps](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary) to build the library... Rest of it is very easy... then [read this](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction)

Comment: yes... but i rather prefer that you build it by your self... it will take little more time but you'll learn lots of things...if you face problem in it... post it here... we'll try to resolve...

Answer (score 0):

The Maps Data API doesn't do what you seem to want to do - search for nearby points of interest, rather its a way to save and query your geo data.

You'll probably want to take a look at the Local Search features of the [Google AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/). [This section](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje) talks about how to use it as a web service, which you can access from your iPhone app.

Comment: cool thanks. But r u sure we cannot do this with map data api ?

Comment: Have u tried this out with your iphone application ? to perform search ?

Comment: The search ur pointing out to is a general search how to perform map based search, as I require lat/long to plot the markers. i have edited my question will expect more answers.

Comment: Again, the Maps Data API is not what you need. It will not return local business and POI results. The AJAX Search API has a Local Search feature, which is what you'd want to use. Look under the section for non Javascript environments.

Comment: Got this for non javascript environment (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) am I on the right path, but I am not interested in the map but lat/long set returned as search result. Can u guide me a bit more.