# How to show Google Maps API Web Services data on IPhone

Tags: ios5, google-maps-api-3

I'am developing an IPhone app, in which I need to show routes between two locations.

And for this I want to make use of Google Maps API services and get the [JSON response][1] from them and I would like to show the data in my App.

I'm entirely new to this implementation

Can anyone let me know ..How to implement this..

I want to use that JSON Data and show routes in my App..

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385924/integrating-google-maps-data-api-with-iphone-and-performing-search